# Unable to resolve this issue on my birt reports

Tags: jboss, struts2, centos, jasper-reports, birt

Unable to resolve this issue on my **birt** reports i have been working on technologies mentioned in the tags and getting this error on my console while i deploy my project on **centOS + JBOSS 5.1.0** but its working fine with tomcat + windows in development.

```
    org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1064)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1272)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4411.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4410.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:413)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at com.mvr.web.permission.PermissionFilter.doFilter(PermissionFilter.java:144)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:135)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:94)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:88)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:62)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.terracotta.modules.tomcat.tomcat_5_5.SessionValve55.invoke(SessionValve55.java:57)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:265)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:82)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1263)
... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl, and the class loader (instance of ) for interface org/w3c/dom/Document have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration used in the signature
   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.newDocument(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.parser.HTMLTextParser.parseHTML(HTMLTextParser.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.parser.TextParser.parse(TextParser.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.util.HTML2Content.processForeignData(HTML2Content.java:437)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.util.HTML2Content.html2Content(HTML2Content.java:418)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startForeign(LayoutEngine.java:627)
   at org.eclipse.birt..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your JBoss deployment, did you remove these jars from the WEB-INF/lib folder:

org.apache.xerces and org.apache.xml.serializer

Here is a link to the steps for using the BIRT POJO Sample Viewer with JBoss that are in the Eclipse wiki:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/BirtPOJO_Viewer_JBOSS_Deployment

Comment: there is no any lib that you have mentioned above in myproject/web-inf/lib folder but still its generating same exception is there something that i am missing?

Comment: Are you using the viewer or just the BIRT runtime jars within your own project?

Comment: i am using BIRT viewer for development while it runs from jsp using different jars and tlds

Comment: Did you install the web viewer yourself? If so (and you didn't already remove it yourself), the xerces jar should be in the web-inf/lib folder of the web viewer.

Comment: thank you dear the problem has been resolved i was using xml-bean.jar in my project and it was conflicting with the jboss jars.